# error:addEventListener is not a function, when i use getElementByClassName

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JavaScript, and can't get this problem solved

Error : btn.addEventListener is not a function

It works when I use query selector, but not when I getElementByClassName

*HTML*

```
<input type="text" class="amount">
     <select>
                <option class="option" value="1">Good</option>
                <option class="option" value="2">Ok</option>
                <option class="option" value="3">Bad</option>
            </select>
 <button class="btn"> Calculate </button>
```

JavaScript

```
const amount = document.getElementsByClassName('amount');
const btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', a());

function a() {
  alert('100');
}
```

The alert fires off on the load of the window!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're accessing HTML elements before they are available, to avoid that use [`$(document).ready`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/).

**[document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)** is an array.

**[addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)** function accepts function defination, you are calling function `addEventListener('click',a())`. It should be `addEventListener('click',a)`

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {


  const amount = document.getElementsByClassName('amount')[0];
  const btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn')[0];

  btn.addEventListener('click', a);

  function a() {
    alert('100');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="amount">
<select>
    <option class="option" value="1">Good</option>
    <option class="option" value="2">Ok</option>
    <option class="option" value="3">Bad</option>
</select>
<button class="btn"> Calculate </button>
```